# Output a Static Block on the Product Description

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I wish to add a Static Block(s) to Magento's product description field in the same way it could be added to a regular page. Example: http://www.screencast.com/t/l5DbjRZagVKv

If I add the code: `{{block type="cms/block" block_id="your_block_id"}}` to the page description of a product it will just output as text. Example:  http://www.screencast.com/t/pUS4CObZ

It is important that I am able to manage static blocks for a range of similar products, for example Electral goods have different Warranty information than Bathroom products. The information will be the same across 100s of products but not all of them.

If there is a solution/workaround that someone could suggest then it would be greatly appreciated. I've been googling all day and their seems to be nothing.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I may not be sure what you want to achieve but according to my understanding i think you want to show the static block to some limited number of products.Is it right?If so than you can create a new category and assign those products to that category.

Now all you need to do is go to your "app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml".

Here you need to check the condition that if the product is of the particular category you defined than you output that block.

To output the static block in the template file you can do following.

```
echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-new-block')->toHtml();
```

Hope you understood what i am trying to say and hope it will help.

Comment: thanks so much. yes I wish to show a static block on the prod page for a number of products, most of them with static blocks per product. e.g: Warranty Info, Freight rates...

I hoped the static blocks could be added to the page without the need for a developer dipping into the code. There will also be the need for a variable amount of static blocks for a product.

In my current CMS I have this functionality in something called 'Content holders' allowing editing common info in one place. A simple tag meant it could be easily added.

How could yr solution work with variable # of stat blocks?

Comment: Static block could only be added to cms pages from admin panel but in product page is not a cms page and i don't think there is other option.

Comment: I did not think so. Your suggestion is still food for thought. your help is much appreciated.